# Only select child category, not grandchildren

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am trying to show which categories belong to a specific post in Wordpress.
I only would like to show the categories that are a child of catID 10 and don't want to show the grandchildren.

So I have this hyrarchie now (this is only a part of it)

```
Areas (parent, catID = 10)
- Pals/Begur (child)
-- Aiguablava (grandchild)
-- Fornells (grandchild)
```

I would only like to show Pals/Begur.

This is the code, it now shows children and grandchildren.

```
<?php
     foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
          if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
               echo $childcat->cat_name.', ';
          }
     }
?>
```

Comment: can you make question title be more specific?))

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `parent` property for the `get_the_category` function, to only get the direct children of a category.

```
foreach((get_the_category( 'parent' => 10 )) as $childcat) {
  ...
}
```

Taken from Wordpress:

> parent : Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category identified by its ID. This does NOT work like the 'child_of' parameter. There is no default for this parameter. [In 2.8.4]

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach((get_the_category('parent'=> 10)) as $childcat) {
    $child_cats = $childcat->term_id;                                    
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'child_of' => $child_cats,
        'hide_empty' => 0
    );

    $grandchild_categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($grandchild_categories as grandchild_category) {
        echo $grandchild_category->cat_name.', ';
    }
}
```